# Adding Pokemon X/Y game to Global Link

Tags: pokemon-x-y, pokemon-global-link

I previously had a Pokemon X game and assigned that game to my Pokemon Global Link account. I recently bought a new Pokemon X game and want to add that game onto my Pokemon Global Link account.

I'm trying to add the code from my cartridge to my Pokemon Game Link but it's not allowing me to do.

What can I do to add my new Pokemon X game while trying to retrieve my previous PokeMiles and other bonuses from my last game?

I already know that I cannot get any Pokemon back so I'm not worried about that.

Comment: Do you have any other gen 6 pokemon games or have you only ever owned X?

Comment: @Pyritie, I own Pokemon Y as well and have that game registered to my account.

Comment: Then you could do what @pinckerman said, but also transfer your pokemiles from your old X to your Y temporarily, so you don't lose them. You can do this through the PGL as well. If you have access to pokebank, you could use that to store your pokemon during the transfer, or just have a friend hold onto them for a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I know, you can assign only one copy of Pokemon X and one of Pokemon Y to your PGL account.

If you want to assign a different Pokemon X copy, you first need to unregister the previous assigned cartridge. To do this, login to Pokemon Global Link, go to *Account Settings*, select your Pokemon X cartridge and select to cancel the current cartridge assignment.

<sub>(Sorry, I can't see the English version of the site, so I don't know the actual names of labels.)</sub>